# Magento 2 : How To Pass Data From Observer to Phtml File

Tags: magento2, orders, event-observer, phtml

I am getting order id from order success event, I want to pass order into phtml page. 
I tried with checkout session but I did not get order id in phtml page.
anyone can help me regarding this.
i am getting order from bellow code

```
$order_ids = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds()[0];
           $order = $this->orderRepository->get($order_ids);
           $orderId  = $order->getIncrementId();
```

set session and now getting session value in phtml page

```
$observer_session = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface');
$order = $observer_session->getValue();
```

Comment: In which page you are trying to pass data

Comment: custom template file

Comment: in phtml file i have written code for product information and call this template under email template file.

Comment: A custom template file is not a page. Can you state which page(s) or layout handle(s) you are trying to access the data on?

Comment: i got solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do like this.

1. From your observer, set the order value into custom session variable.
2. On phtml file, get those value from session variable.

Here are the demo code.

```
protected $_coreSession;

public function __construct(
    -----
    \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $coreSession
    ){
    $this->_coreSession = $coreSession;
    ----
}

public function setValue(){
    $this->_coreSession->start();
    $this->_coreSession->setMessage('YOUR_CUSTOM_VALUE');
}

public function getValue(){
    $this->_coreSession->start();
    return $this->_coreSession->getMessage();
}

public function unSetValue(){
    $this->_coreSession->start();
    return $this->_coreSession->unsMessage();
}
```

Comment: i have set order id with session $data['order']= $order->getIncrementId(); and call in template $orderId = this->getData('order');. but its not working for me

Comment: I am talking about magento core session.

Comment: can you help me how ..

Comment: I update my answer with code. Kindly check. And if it help, please accept as soluiton, so it will help other in community as well.

Comment: you can get the value using objectmanaget into phtml file.

Comment: $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');


echo $customerSession->getMyValue(); what should i use instead of customer session

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79261/discussion-between-er-sarvesh-v-tiwari-and-dhiren-vasoya).

Comment: $observer_session = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface');    echo $order = $observer_session->getValue(); its not working for me

Comment: can you specify the code which you have done to save value from observer.

Comment: Charm bro Its working super ...... suuuuuuuuuuuper..

Comment: Hope you get answer.

Comment: @SarveshTiwari accept the answer if it solved your issue so it could help others